# $ N(M\cap H) = M $, $ M \leq NS \leq G $. $ NS = M $ or $ NS = G $ of maximality of $ M $. Let $ G = NS $. Why $ H = S $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a finite group and $ N $ is normal subgroup of $ G $ such that $ G = HN $ for some subgroup $ H $ of $ G $. Suppose $ M $ is a maximal subgroup of $ G $ with $ N \leq M $. Let subgroup $ S $ of $ G $ such that $ M\cap H \leq S < H $. Then $ N(M\cap H) \leq NS \leq G $. Since $ N(M\cap H) = M $, $ M \leq NS \leq G $. $ NS = M $ or $ NS = G $ of maximality of $ M $. Let $ G = NS $. Why $ H = S $ ?

Comment: I don't quite follow you: the maximal subgroup of $G$ such that $N\subseteq M$ is $G$ itself!

Comment: I want show $ M\cap H $ is a maximal subgroup of $ H $.

Comment: Well, if $M=G$, $M\cap H=H$, and it is maximal among subgroups of $H$. What definition of *maximal*  do you have?

Comment: If $ M \leq H \leq G $, then $ H = G $ or $ H = M $.

Comment: I now need show $ H = S $ .

Comment: So you mean a maximal *proper*  subgroup?

Comment: yes, maximal proper subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the *Second Isomorphism Theorem*, we can write, if $SN=G$:
$$G/N=\begin{cases}SN/N\simeq S/S\cap N,\\[1ex]
HN/N\simeq H/H\cap N.
\end{cases}$$
Now, since $S\subset H$, $S\cap N\subset H\cap N$. Also, since $H\subset M$, $H\cap N=(H\cap M)\cap N\subset S\cap N$. Hence $H\cap N=S\cap N$. The isomorphism $S/S\cap N\simeq H/H\cap N$ then implies  $S\simeq H$. As $S$ is a subgroup of H, and they're finite groups, this means $S=H$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $H\cap N\vartriangleleft H,S\cap N\vartriangleleft S$, by second isomorphism theorem
$$
HN/N\cong H/H\cap N \hspace{4 mm} \text{and } \hspace{4 mm} SN/N\cong S/S\cap N
$$
Also $G=HN=SN$, so
$$
H/H\cap N\cong S/S\cap N\tag{1}
$$
If $S<H$, then $S\cap N<H\cap N$.

Suppose $g\in H, g\notin S$. Then $g(H\cap N)\notin S/S\cap N$, contradicting $(1)$. Thus $H=S$.